# Why does CVS omit folders when committing?

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I do have a project with structure

```
project/lib/lib1/subfolders
           /lib2/...
```

`lib2` was recently added and is now in CVS. When committing `/project`, the changed files in `/project` and `/project/lib2` are part of the commit, however `lib2/subfolders` are not. I can commit each subfolder of `lib2` individually without error but would like them to be part of the full commit.

Why does CVS omit these subfolders when committing?

Comment: Maybe there is a "recursive add"?

Comment: There isn't. Also I'm committing /project and it takes /project/lib2 (or any changes in lib1 and below by the way) so it already is recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into `lib2/CVS/entries` I've found the following structure:

```
/index.html/1.3/Sat Mar 16 09:58:04 2013//
/humans.txt/1.1/Sat Mar 16 09:58:00 2013//
/robots.txt/1.1/Sat Mar 16 09:58:04 2013//
D
```

In lib1 however, instead of `D`, each directory was shown separately:

```
D/css////
D/fonts////
D/js////
D/img////
```

The problem is obviously that in lib2 the folders are not mentioned in the `entries` file.

I've now changed the `entries` files to explicitly contain the directory and problem appears to be solved. It's still unclear what when wrong when adding lib2 though.